# LdapContextSource close connection

Tags: java, ldap

I am using

```
LdapContextSource ldapContextSource = new LdapContextSource();
```

to create connection after setting url, userDn and password.

I need to close this connection but could not find any way. How can I close it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ldap closes its context itself each time it performs any operation. So there is no need to close context.

Answer (score 1):

LdapContextSource acts as a factory that creates context instances. What you need to do is to close the context (DirContext) returned from that class (i.e. getReadOnlyContext(), getReadWriteContext(), etc.).

Alternatively you could pass the context you need to close to static utility method **org.springframework.ldap.support.LdapUtils.closeContext(DirContext)**.

Hope that helps.